# Correct way to unload stream from audio and video elements

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

What is the correct way to unload the stream from a `<audio>` or `<video>` element ?

Lets say i have a `<audio src="music.mp3">` streaming some nice music.

And i have a `<video>` streaming my handsome good looking face with the webcam using `getUserMedia()`.

I'm using `element.src = '';` at the moment but Firefox seems to give a warning in the console about URI not being valid.
And also it doesn't seem to work for the webcam stream using `getUserMedia()` which just keeps streaming.

I know HTML5 and `getUserMedia()` are the new stuff and dont work so good yet but i would like to know the correct way to unload the stream even if its not working correctly at the moment in the different browsers.

Comment: Do you want to only unload or destroy the element completely?

Comment: Just remove the stream.